# is it possible for a thread 'x' in vector to finish before the x.join() call?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

i have a vector of threads in my code in which i am pushing threads. After ~100 calls of function "func" i get "terminate called without an active exception". I have read that this error means that "join" is not called for a thread. In the code below i call "join" for every thread in the vector and in my program i already called function about 100 times but if i call it again the code crashes. Is it possible that a thread, let's say thread_10, finishes before the end of the first 'for' loop, and by the second the function 'join' cannot be called because for thread_10 because there is no such thread?
If it is possible how can i prevent this?

```
void func(){
    vector<std::thread> my_threads;
    for (deque<unsigned int>::iterator it = candidates.begin(); it != candidates.end(); it++)  
    {       
        Query* quer = &queries[*it];
        my_threads.push_back(std::thread(foo, param));  
    }     

    for (std::thread &thread: my_threads)
    {  
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: `join` works if thread is finished. In every valid (deadlock free) use of `join` you don't know if joined thread has finished yet or not. Please try to reproduce your example as SSCCE.

Comment: Your code seems good, which compiler/platform are you using? Have you access to the stacktrace when it crashes?

Comment: I am using gcc 4.6 on linux mint. How can i see if i have access to the stacktrace? i am new to c++. I only get the error and the program stops. I will edit the answer with the pseudo code of the rest of the code, but i think there are no problems there.

Answer (score 2):

If the first part of your function throws an exception, e.g. because there are not enough resources to create a new thread, then the function aborts with an exception, without joining the already created threads. Most likely that's the reason why you see *terminate called without an active exception*.

The following should work:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
SCOPE_EXIT {
    for (auto&& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
};
for (auto&& candidate : candidates) {
    // ...
    threads.emplace_back(callable, candiate, ...);
}
```

**Edit:** `SCOPE_EXIT` is a well-known construct, that is for example defined in the header [ScopeGuard](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/ScopeGuard.h) of the *folly library*. I have used it to make clear, that the cleanup has to happen at the end of the function (scope) - regardless whether it is exited regularly or within an exception.

Comment: I searched about SCOPE_EXIT but this doesn't seem to be in standard c++11. Am i wrong? How can i include this macro?
Note: i don't use boost library for my threads.
Is it wrong to use a vector for so many threads? Should i do something else to avoid creating all these?

Comment: I figured out that the problem occurs while calling "push_back" in the vector "threads". I used deque instead of vector and the problem remains the same, but now i get "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error' - what(): Resource temporarily unavailable". This is thrown after filling the deque with 310 records already. I didn't use SCOPE EXIT because the problem will remain, as i won't be able to push the thread in the vector (and i really need it).

Comment: @user2501980: As you have a better understanding of the problem now, you should ask another question: _How can I create more than 310 threads?_